# Web scraping content behind a login page

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

My goal here is to scrape data from a webpage that I have to login to using PowerShell. To be transparent, this is a real estate type website and I'm not aware of anyone else trying to scrape this data so I don't really want to divulge the full URL.

I've got working code that I believe logs into the webpage but trying to visit any URLs beyond that somehow says I'm not logged in and returns no data.

This code is the result of watching the Opera browser's dev tools while logging in and when navigating to the desired list of content. I can right click and copy as PowerShell the GET request but even sending that back hasn't been successful.

`$DashboardGet` comes back with a link property with the Login URL which tells me the data I'm sending (in the header? Or in the SessionVariable) isn't correctly keeping the session logged in?

But I can see and verify `$PageLogin` definitely gets logged into the website, I just cannot seem to grab anything beyond this.

```
$base_URL = 'https://site.webpage.com/'

$site = Invoke-WebRequest $base_URL

$user = Import-Clixml C:\Apps\website_login.xml

$site.Forms.fields.email = $user.UserName

$site.Forms.fields.password = $user.Password

$LoginPayload = $site.Forms.fields | ConvertTo-Json

$loginSite = $site.Forms[0].Action

$PageLogin = Invoke-WebRequest $loginSite -UseBasicParsing -Method POST -Body $LoginPayload -SessionVariable ScapeWebPage

$ScapeWebPage.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", "lots of boring characters here", "/", "site.webpage.com")))
$ScapeWebPage.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("key01", "more boring characters", "/", "site.webpage.com")))

$DashboardGet = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://site.webpage.com/app/dashboard" `
-WebSession $ScapeWebPage -Method GET

$DashboardGet
```

Comment: Your `$ScapeWebPage` variable is not defined for your first call to `Invoke-WebRequest`.  Perhaps its simply missing a referrer or domain origin on subsequent calls.

Comment: @leeharvey1 sadly the website is being stubborn and that made no difference. I moved the `-SessionVariable` to the first `Invoke-WebRequest` but still only see the Forgot Pass link. I even tried installing PowerShell core 7.1 for the `PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect` param but that didn't help rather I cant login now.